# Can the TP-Link AC1750 be wall-mounted?

Tags: router

I'm looking at the TP-Link AC1750 router. The photos only show me some of its faces; and showcase it placed on a surface - table or shelf. No image of the back. Does it have wall-mounting holes, or come with a wall-mounting bracket of any kind?

Couldn't figure it out from the manufacturer's website nor from newegg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

You can see it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os2jt4cpIFk) at 3:12:

[image: Bottom of the TP-Link Archer C7 AC1750 router with two wall mounting holes visible]